# Grails map domain class to a view that already exists in oracle database

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a database view already created called FACULTY_VIEW and would like to map a grails domain class to it. 
Here is the Domain:

```
class FacultyInformation {

    def faculty_pidm
    def faculty_person_id
    def faculty_first_name
    def faculty_last_name

    static mapping = {
        table 'FACULTY_VIEW'
        version false
        cache 'read-only',inlcude:'non-lazy'

        faculty_pidm column:'FACULTY_PIDM'
        faculty_person_id column:'FACULTY_PERSON_ID'
        faculty_first_name column:'FACULTY_FIRST_NAME'
        faculty_last_name column:'FACULTY_LAST_NAME'        
    }

}
```

And here is my Controller snippet for that Domain that is trying to do a search:

```
facultySearchList = FacultyInformation.createCriteria().list (max: params.max, offset: params.offset, sort:params.sort, order: params.order) {
    ilike("faculty_last_name", searchTerm )
}
```

**Upon start-up I get this error message(which I would expect):**

> | Error 2015-11-11 14:58:33,675 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table FACULTY_VIEW add id
>   number(19,0) not null | Error 2015-11-11 14:58:33,677
>   [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - ORA-00942: table
>   or view does not exist

And then once I perform the search I get this error mesaage:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   faculty_last_name of: facultyinformation.FacultyInformation

I of course don't plan on inserting or deleting from this view, as I just was to search it.

I'm guessing in one way or another this is a hibernate issue / configuration issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Part 2:
Here is my db changelog to create the view:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
        changeSet(author: "jdannucci (generated)", id: "1447432810497-1") {
            createView("""
      SELECT DISTINCT SIRASGN_PIDM AS faculty_pidm, SPRIDEN_ID AS faculty_person_id, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME AS faculty_first_name, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME AS faculty_last_name
    FROM SSBSECT , SCBCRSE, SCRLEVL SC, SIRASGN SA, SPRIDEN
    WHERE SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = (SELECT MAX(STVTERM_CODE) FROM STVTERM
                                            WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(STVTERM_START_DATE) AND TRUNC(STVTERM_END_DATE))
    AND SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE=SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
    AND SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB=SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB
    AND SSBSECT_CRN = SIRASGN_CRN
    AND SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE != 'FE'
    AND SIRASGN_PRIMARY_IND = 'Y'
    AND SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = SIRASGN_TERM_CODE
    AND SCRLEVL_LEVL_CODE = '01'
    AND SCRLEVL_SUBJ_CODE = SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE
    AND SCRLEVL_CRSE_NUMB = SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
    AND SCRLEVL_EFF_TERM = (SELECT MAX(SCRLEVL_EFF_TERM)
                    FROM SCRLEVL
                    WHERE SCRLEVL_SUBJ_CODE = SC.SCRLEVL_SUBJ_CODE
                    AND  SCRLEVL_CRSE_NUMB = SC. SCRLEVL_CRSE_NUMB
                    AND SCRLEVL_EFF_TERM <= SSBSECT_TERM_CODE)
    AND SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM = (SELECT MAX(SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM)
         FROM SATURN.SCBCRSE X
         WHERE X.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE=SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE
         AND X.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB=SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
         AND X.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM <= SSBSECT_TERM_CODE)
    AND SPRIDEN_PIDM = SIRASGN_PIDM
    AND SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL
    ORDER BY faculty_last_name
    """, viewName: 'FACULTY_VIEW')
         }
    }
```

And here is my new Domain:

```
package facultyinformation

class FacultyInformation {

    def faculty_pidm
    def faculty_person_id
    def faculty_first_name
    def faculty_last_name

    static mapping = {
        table 'FACULTY_VIEW'
        version false
        cache 'read-only',inlcude:'non-lazy'

        faculty_pidm column:'FACULTY_PIDM'
        faculty_person_id column:'FACULTY_PERSON_ID'
        faculty_first_name column:'FACULTY_FIRST_NAME'
        faculty_last_name column:'FACULTY_LAST_NAME'        
    }

}
```

Datasource:

```
development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "none" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:PPRD"

            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        }
    }
```

Here's controller code that gives me the error:

```
facultySearchList = FacultyInformation.createCriteria().list (max: params.max, offset: params.offset, sort:params.sort, order: params.order) {
                        ilike("faculty_last_name", searchTerm )
                }
```

Here's the error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: faculty_last_name of: facultyinformation.FacultyInformation
```

Getting very frustrated.. I'm wondering if it would just be easier to avoid hibernate all together???

Answer (score 0):

Based on this part of the error message, the database connection doesn't see your view:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Obviously, make sure the view does exist.

If the view does exist, check the datasource configuration and ensure it is using to the right database and that the user specified in the connection parameters has access to the view.

Comment: The view does exist, I'm using the right database, and the user is the same. If I change the dbCreate = "update" to dbCreate = "none". Then the first error goes away.. Makes sense since I'm telling hibernate to not try and create / update the table/view.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's essential to use the db_migration plugin?

Comment: Grails is probably not doing the sql that you expect.  Try enabling logging on the migration plugin to see exactly what it is sending to the database: http://grysz.com/2011/11/08/log-sql-output-with-grails-database-migration-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I created some views with the db-migration plugin by executing the SQL explicitly, i.e. using `sql('''CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` instead of `createView("""`

Also, you'll want to exclude your views from GORM table updates by implementing `DdlFilterConfiguration` as described in this presentation by Burt Beckwith: http://www.slideshare.net/gr8conf/gorm-burt-beckwith2011

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the easiest way is to add an ID column to the view.  Since all of the tables in the query have a unique sequence number index, you can add the following column to the view (I don't want to reveal the real proprietary column names, so we'll call the index <table_name>_ID, even though that's fake).

```
SSBSECT_ID||'-'||SCBCRSE_ID||'-'||SCRLEVL_ID||'-'||SIRASGN_ID||'-'||SPRIDEN_ID as SURROGATE_ID
```

Then you change the domain class so that it looks like this:

```
package facultyinformation
```

class FacultyInformation {

```
String id
def faculty_pidm
def faculty_person_id
def faculty_first_name
def faculty_last_name

static mapping = {
    table 'FACULTY_VIEW'
    version false
    id column: 'SURROGATE_ID'
    cache 'read-only',inlcude:'non-lazy'

    faculty_pidm column:'FACULTY_PIDM'
    faculty_person_id column:'FACULTY_PERSON_ID'
    faculty_first_name column:'FACULTY_FIRST_NAME'
    faculty_last_name column:'FACULTY_LAST_NAME'        
}
```

}